# Mixed Fortran/C++ with intel compilers: undefined references to 'system_'

Tags: c++, fortran

I am working on a large mixed-language code in Fortran 1990 and C++ 11. I recently compiled on a new platform with intel compilers (which I have successfully used before), specifically Intel Version 19.1.1.217.

I have boiled the issue down to a simple test:

`f.F90`

```
subroutine ff()

  implicit none
  call system('echo y')

end subroutine ff
```

`main.cc`

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C"
{
  void ff_(void);
}
int main(void)
{
  ff_();
  return 0;
}
```

I have emulated exactly how my code is built, which boils down to this:

```
mpif90 -f90=ifort -c f.F90 -o f.o
mpicxx -cxx=icpc -c main.cc -o main.o
mpicxx -cxx=icpc main.o f.o -L/software/intel/2020.1/compilers_and_libraries/linux/lib/intel64 -lifcore
```

...after which I get the following:

```
f.o: In function `ff_':
f.F90:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `system_'
```

I am aware that calls to `system()` are not part of the stardard, but I can successfully compile and run the following with no problem:

`p.F90`:

```
program ff

  implicit none
  call system('echo y')

end program
```

`mpif90 -f90=ifort p.f90 -o pexe && ./pexe`

```
y
```

This suggests to me that using `mpif90 -f90=ifort` is imlicitly telling the linker to link in some extra libraries, but running `ldd` on the resulting executable shows a subset of the libraries linked in when I compile a simple C++ program.

What do I need to link to stop this error?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I stumbled upon the solution immediately after asking this question. By using `mpif90 -f90=ifort -v (source files)` I was able to see everything that was being linked, and tried each library one at a time until it worked.